# Mocktest Local JSONP throws parseerror "Callback not called"

Tags: jquery, ajax, testing, mocking, jsonp

I got a `c:\index.html` and define a JSONP Call using jQuery:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/test/jsonServlet'
if (mockTest)
    url = 'file:bla.json';
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  error: function(a,b,c) {
    console.debug("ERR", b, c);
  }
});
```

The `c:\bla.json` is like this:

```
var f = this.jQuery.expando;
console.debug("BLA", f);
f = this[f].handle;
console.debug("TYPE", typeof f);
f({'decoration':'Hello World!'}); // call the callback!
```

There are three messages:

```
BLA jQuery1705534191443584859
TYPE function 
ERR parsererror jQuery1705534191443584859_1372951198352 was not called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called `jQuery1705534191443584859` instead of `jQuery1705534191443584859_1372951198352`.

Now it works, i used to use:

```
    var f;
    for ( var k in this)
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(k) 
           && k.indexOf(this.jQuery.expando) > -1 
           && k.indexOf('_') > -1)
            f = k;

    this[f]({'decoration':'Hello World!'});
```

now, local mock-tests working.